# Does this $3\times 3$ matrix exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Does a real $3\times 3$ matrix $A$ that satisfies conditions $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$ and $A^2+A^T=I$ ($I$ is an identity matrix) exist?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is $A$ real or complex valued?

Comment: Sorry, It should be real, I forgot to mention that. I have tried writing down the components of $A^T$ and $A^2$ and creating equations, and it really looks like a quadric, resp. quadratic form, but to find a solution for those 11 equations is a work for a slave, then I thought maybe it could be a matrix of a projection, but got nowhere.

Comment: Agreed, manually solving the simultaneous equations is not what is intended here.

Comment: There is in the 2x2 case...

Comment: In the 2x2 case, $a_{11}=\varphi, a_{12} = a_{21} = 0$ and $a_{22}=-{\varphi}$.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst : I don't think this works since $\varphi$ and $-\varphi$ don't both satisfy $x^2+x-1=0$.  Michael Grant has just added to his post that there is no solution for any size matrix.

Comment: I did the calculation in Maple and I'm pretty sure i got the identity matrix....I'll do it again when I get home.

Comment: No, dammit...  Epic fail!!  I must have made an error....

Comment: s'ok, I made more than one below as well!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Many thanks to user1551 for this contribution.] First, let us show that the eigenvalues of $A$ must be real. The equation $A^2+A^T=I$ implies that
$$A^T=I−A^2 \quad\text{and}\quad (A^T)^2+A=I.$$ Substituting the first equation into the second yields
$$I−2A^2+A^4+A=I \quad\Longrightarrow\quad A^4−2A^2+A=A(A−I)(A^2+A−I)=0.$$
The eigenvalues must therefore satisfy $\lambda(\lambda−1)(\lambda^2+\lambda−1)=0$, which has the roots $\{0,1,(-1+\sqrt{5})/2,(-1-\sqrt{5})2\}$, all real. In fact, we will show that only the last two are possible.

Let $A=QUQ^T$ be the Schur decomposition of $A$, where $Q$ is unitary and $U$ is upper triangular. Because the eigenvalues of $A$ are real, both $Q$ and $U$ are real as well. Then 
$$A^2+A^T=I\quad\Longrightarrow QUQ^TQUQ^T+QU^TQ^T=I\quad\Longrightarrow\quad U^2+U^T=I.$$
$U^2$ is upper triangular, and $U^T$ is lower triangular. The only way it is possible to satisfy the equation is if $U$ is diagonal.

(Alternatively, $A$ commutes with $A^T$ because $A^T=I-A^2$. Therefore $A$ is a normal matrix. Since we have shown that all eigenvalues of $A$ are real, it follows that $A$ is orthogonally diagonalisable as $QUQ^T$ for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$ and real diagonal matrix $U$.)

If $U$ is diagonal, then $A$ was symmetric; and the diagonal elements of $U$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Each must separately satisfy $\lambda^2+\lambda-1=0$. So $\lambda=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$. But there are three eigenvalues, so one of them is repeated. There is no way for the resulting sum to be zero.

Since the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to $\mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(A)$, this is a contradiction.

EDIT: I'm going to add that it does not matter that the matrix is $3\times 3$. There is no square matrix of any size that satisfies the conditions put forth. There is no way to choose $n>0$ values from the set $\{(-1+\sqrt{5})/2,(-1-\sqrt{5})/2\}$ that have a zero sum.

Comment: $x^2 - x - 1$ cannot possibly be the characteristic polynomial. It's quadratic.

Comment: Yep, you're right, editing and/or deleting

Comment: No need to delete the answer, you can push through rather easily. The eigenvalues must lie amongst the roots of the polynomial. It's easy to see that no combination of the roots will give $0$.

Comment: Indeed. Please check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for catching the glaring error!

Comment: How can you say $U^T U = I$? $U$ is unitary not orthogonal. $A^2 is Q U^2 Q^*$ but $A^T $ is  $(Q^*)^T U^T Q$

Comment: @ACARCHAU The equation $A^2+A^T=I$ implies that (a) $A^T=I-A^2$ and (b) $(A^T)^2+A=I$. Substitute (a) into (b), we get $I-2A^2+A^4+A=I$, which simplifies to $A^4-2A^2+A=A(A-I)(A^2+A-I)=0$. The polynomial $x(x-1)(x^2+x-1)$ has only real roots. Therefore $A$ is *orthogonally* triangularisable.

Comment: There should be according to Shurs decomposition definition $U^+$ instead of $U^T$, where + means conjugate transpose and by the definition of unitary matrix $UU^+=U^+U=I$

Comment: The matrix is real, so conjugate transpose is not necessary. But we could extend this to complex matrices if we did that.

Comment: @user1551, that is nice. Didn't think of that.

Comment: Folks, a real unitary matrix is orthonormal.

Comment: The Schur decomposition for real matrices might involve complex numbers, google for real schur decomposition. In this particular case it does have a real schur decomposition, but it needs @user1551's argument, it is not obvious.

Comment: Good point. I will work on a correction. Good job.

Comment: @user1551, I suggest that you turn your comment into an answer, since it is an important part of our combined work.

Comment: If you don't mind, I can edit your answer. I think this way is easier and less repetitive.

Comment: Sure. Let me take a pass and then you feel free to edit.

Comment: Nice edit, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I consider the case where $A$ is restricted to real matrices so $A^\top=A^*$.

Let  $\lambda$ be any eigenvalue of $A$, and let $x$, $\|x\| > 0$ be a corresponding eigenvector.

Multiply on the left by $x^*$ and on the right by $x$ to get

$x^* (A^2 x) + (Ax)^*x = \|x\|^2$, i.e., $\lambda^2\|x\|^2 + \overline{\lambda}\|x\|^2 = \|x\|^2$.

As the right hand side is non-zero we must have $\lambda \neq 0$ and $ \lambda^2 + \overline{\lambda} = 1.$

Let $\lambda = a + ib$ with $a,b$ real. We get $$a^2 -b^2 + a = 1$$ and $$2ab - b = 0.$$ Note, $a \neq 1/2$ as then $a^2 + a - 1 = b^2$, a consequence of the first equation becomes impossible. SO the second equation above implies $b=0$ and all eigenvalues are real and are roots of $x^2 + x - 1 = 0$. The rest follows as above solution by Michael Grant, i.e., the trace being the sum of three numbers in $\{ \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} \}$ cannot be $0$.